# How to use chainlink VRF v1 in my smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I am trying to use getRandomNumber() function from my VRFConsumer smart contract to get random numbers. Will I get the random number immediately after I call this or do I also have to call the fulfillRandomness() function? If yes, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call the `getRandomNumber()` function you will need to wait until the `fulfillRandomness()` is called by the coordinator.
You don't need to do anything, just check the storage variable where you store the number (if you used a storage variable) after a minute or two.